# How can I make y-axis lines that match the x-axis lines from theme_clean()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, gridlines, ggthemes

I'm going to be producing a lot of visuals for a report. My boss really likes the `theme_clean()` horizontal lines but wants me to **add the same lines to the x-axis.** Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = hp)) + 
  theme_clean(base_size=18)
```

[image]

How can I get the same style for my x-axis ticks (going vertical).

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Simply typing `theme_clean` into the console shows you the default values used by `theme_clean` for `panel.grid.major.y` which we then can use to set the values for `panel.grid.major.x` accordingly using `theme()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = hp)) + 
  theme_clean(base_size=18) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "dotted"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>